# IAM policy for restricting Glue resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to limit a user to a specific database. User should be able to do all the actions to that database and its tables.

All the examples I found in the documentations limit the Action, but never Resource.

The example below gives user access to all the databases and tables. What should be put in `Resource` field to restrict access to a single database?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Action": [
          "glue:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why vote downs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Glue doesn't support resource-level permissions.

You can control access to data by restricting underlying S3 buckets. However, if you give `glue:GetTable` access to a user, it can list all the tables in all the databases. Or `glue:DeleteTable`...

Same goes for Athena.